# How do you decompose the sum of a series of interger variables multiplied by a coefficient back into the varaibles?

Tags: c, math

I have 4 integer variables, `a,b,c,d` that vary between 0 and `A,B,C,D` respectively, i.e.

```
0 <= a < A
0 <= b < B
0 <= c < C
0 <= d < D
```

I encode them into an index as tightly as possible so that each unique (a,b,c,d) combo produces a unique index:

```
int index(int a, int b, int c, int d) { 
    return a + A*b + A*B*c + A*B*C*d;
}
```

Given an index, I want to get back the original `a,b,c,d` values that generated it.  I can figure out the value for `a` but not the rest:

```
int index = ...

int a = index % A;
int b = ...
```

Comment: How would you do it in the special case where A = B = C = D?

Comment: The inverse of multiplication is called...?

Comment: a + A*b + A*B*c + A*B*C*d == a + A*(b+B*(c+C*d)) ... from that it should be obvious.

Comment: @KerrekSB - Not sure what you mean by this comment - obviously the inverse is dividing, but it feels like it is more complex that your comment suggests.  Please correct me if I am wrong.  P.s. I love your avatar, Commander Keen used to by my favourite game!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, shouldn't be a problem. Take for instance A=B=C=D=10, and say, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4 then you'll have index=1234.

Comment: BTW, do you actually mean `0 <= a < A` rather than `0 <= a <= A` (etc.)?  Otherwise, you won't obtain unique encodings.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - Yes, I made a mistake.  Ill correct this

Comment: @aioobe Oliver was not implying that it's a problem. When the coefficients are all equal, it's a base conversion, which hopefully everyone knows how to do. The generalization when the coefficients are different is simple and obvious (if one has a basic education in modulo arithmetic, as every programmer should).

Comment: Are the down votes for asking a question with a simple answer or off topic or something else I am confused?

Comment: Lack of effort maybe.

Comment: Obviously the down voters are very smart because this was far from obvious to me!

Comment: Once you have a, subtraction gives you A*b + A*B*c + A*B*C*d ... the most obvious thing in the world is to divide by A, as Kerrek suggested. Since you know how to get a from the original, you know how to get b from b + B*c + B*C*d. And the subtraction isn't necessary because integer division eliminates the remainder. Again, just a little effort, not so much smarts.

Comment: " Not sure what you mean by this comment - obviously the inverse is dividing, but it feels like it is more complex that your comment suggests." -- to create the value you had to multiply by a factor and then insert the next variable. The inverse is to divide by a factor and extract the next variable: `b = (index / A) % B`. Then `c = (index / (A*B)) % C`, `d = (index / (A*B*C))`. The method in my answer is cleaner, and more efficient if A,B,C aren't constant. [I've edited my answer to include both methods.]

Comment: Tthe requirement for the function to be an [injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) places some constraints on the choices of A,B,C,D.

Comment: Eh? A, B, C, and D can be any positive integers. The value returned by index is in the range 0 ... (A*B*C*D - 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = index % A;
index /= A;
b = index % B;
index /= B;
c = index % C;
index /= C;
d = index;
```

Or

```
a = index % A;
b = (index / A) % B;
c = (index / (A*B)) % C;
d = (index / (A*B*C));
```

Assuming that you correct your conditions to

```
0 <= a < A
0 <= b < B
0 <= c < C
0 <= d < D
```

With `<=` instead of `<` you don't have a unique mapping.